# How to define a custom main page on a YUIDoc-generated documentation

Tags: javascript, html, windows, yui, yuidoc

I've been playing with [YUIDoc](http://yui.github.com/yuidoc/) and I find it fantastic.

By the way, I don't find a way to define my own main page content for the auto-generated documentation site (custom content inside the auto-generated `index.html`).

How can I define the main page content - *if this is possible, of course* -?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

YUI Doc is quite themable, so in theory this should be quite easy:

[Fork YUI Doc](https://github.com/yui/yuidoc) or modify your current YUI Doc installation.

- Add your own theme under `yuidoc/themes`. Copying the default theme is probably a good place to start, **or** copy over the partials/files you want to override.
- In [`index.handlebars`](https://github.com/yui/yuidoc/blob/master/themes/default/partials/index.handlebars) you add your custom content.
- You can also change the [main.handlebars](https://github.com/yui/yuidoc/blob/master/themes/default/layouts/main.handlebars) to include custom CSS, JS and/or markup.

When you now build the docs, use the --themedir switch to use your new theme:

```
$ yuidoc --themedir ./mytheme
```

**Read more**: [On YUI Doc theming](http://yui.github.com/yuidoc/themes/index.html).

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I forgot to auto-answer, or just drop the question, I found this some days ago. Anyway, because the answer is useful, it's a good reason to keep the Q&A for other visitors! Thanks :D